# Multiple conditions in having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like below (using SQL server 2008 R2):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IsBad] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Insert into Data  values(100,'Book!',1)
Insert into Data  values(100,'Booklki**',1)
Insert into Data  values(100,'Book',0)
Insert into Data  values(100,'New Book ~~',1)
Insert into Data  values(100,'New Book',0)
Insert into Data  values(100,'B00k…>',1)
Insert into Data  values(101,'Tim3#',1)
Insert into Data  values(101,'%Timer%',1)
Insert into Data  values(101,'T1mer**',1)
Insert into Data  values(101,'Tim6',1)
Insert into Data  values(101,'Time@me',1)
Insert into Data  values(102,'ABC',0)
Insert into Data  values(102,'CDE',0)
```

I need to select all the `ID` which are having all `IsBad = 1`. So, querying above table will return ID: `101` . It must not return `102` or `100` because these IDs are having at least one `IsBad=0`.

I tried below query

```
select id,count(distinct isBad) as Total
from Data
group by id
having count(distinct isBad)= 1
```

This query includes the IDs which are having all `IsBad=0`. but I dont need that. I tried to add some more conditions in `having` clause using `AND` , but getting error.

How to proceed ? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I need to run the query against a table having 50 Million records. So, the query needs to be optimized to return the result in less time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  *
from    Data d1
where   not exists 
        (
        select  *
        from    Data d2
        where   d1.id = d2.id
                and d2.IsBad = 0
        )
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adca6/2/0)

If you're just looking for the `id`, you can use:

```
select  distinct id
... rest of the query is the same ...
```

Comment: +1 : Like this... I need to run this query against a table which is having 50 Million records. So the query taking lot of time. Can this be optimized ? I have edited my question.

Comment: Adding an index on `(id, IsBad)` would help

Answer (score 2):

Inverse it - you want "all the ID which have all IsBad = 1", which means the ID can't have any IsBad = 0:

```
SELECT ID FROM Data WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM Data WHERE IsBad = 0
)
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest query ... However, these are taking long time to execute against a table having around 50M records...Can these be optimized to return result in less time ?

Answer (score 1):

The slowness of the current answer is likely due to the use of `where not exists` clause.  I typically get around this peformance issue by using a `left join` and checking for the absence of a match.

```
select *
from Data d1
left join (select * from Data where IsBad = 0) d2
  on d1.id = d2.id
where d2.id is null
```

This is an old post so it probably will not help the original individual but perhaps others will benefit.